# How can I draw this tiling image on LaTex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

A tiling representation of Zeckendorf's theorem[image]

Comment: Have you tried it yourself first? If so, please show what you have done, then contributors can work with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possible way to reproduce your screenshot. It is certainly not the most general nor elegant way, but to give you a start (since this is your first question here).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\Zeckendorf}[2]{%
\foreach \X[count=\Z] in {#1}
{\draw[thick,fill=\X] (\Z,#2) -- (\Z+1,#2) -- (\Z+1,#2+1) -- (\Z,#2+1);
\ifnum\Z=4
\node at (\Z+0.5,#2-0.4){$n-1$};
\fi
\ifnum\Z=5
\node at (\Z+0.5,#2-0.4){$n$};
\fi
\ifnum\Z>5
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ZZ}{\Z-5}
\node at (\Z+0.5,#2-0.4){$n+\ZZ$};
\fi
}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Zeckendorf{white,white,white,white,white,blue,blue,red}{0}
\Zeckendorf{white,white,white,white,white,blue,red,red}{-2}
\Zeckendorf{white,white,white,white,white,red,red,red}{-4}
\Zeckendorf{white,white,white,white,blue,blue,blue,blue}{-6}
\Zeckendorf{white,white,white,white,blue,blue,red,red}{-8}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the approximately `pi` border... lol

Comment: +1 for the answer....and for the conversion of your icon. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help with the code. I'm new to LaTex, so I couldn't figure it out!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a hammersledge to obtain this image. A simple tabular will do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{boldline} 
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\colourcells}{O{2}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{\cellcolor{#2}\bigstrut}}
\newcommand{\redcell}{\cellcolor{Red}\strut}
\newcommand{\mathcell}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\boldmath$#1$\bigstrut}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\itshape
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{2.2ex}
\begin{tabular}{*{8}{p{0.7cm}|}}
    \hline
& & & & & \colourcells{NavyBlue} & \redcell \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{} & \mathcell{n{-}1} & \mathcell{n} & \mathcell{n {+} 1} & \mathcell{n {+} 2} & \mathcell{n {+} 3} \\
\hline
 & & & & &\redcell & \colourcells{NavyBlue}
  \\
 \hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{} & \mathcell{n{-}1} & \mathcell{n} & \mathcell{n {+} 1} & \mathcell{n {+} 2} & \mathcell{n {+} 3} \\
\hline
 & & & & &\redcell &\redcell &\redcell\rule[-4.5ex]{1pt}{0ex} \\
 \hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{} & \mathcell{n{-}1} & \mathcell{n} & \mathcell{n {+} 1} & \mathcell{n {+} 2} & \mathcell{n {+} 3} \\
\hline
 & & & &
  \colourcells{NavyBlue} &\colourcells{NavyBlue} \\
 \hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{} & \mathcell{n{-}1} & \mathcell{n} & \mathcell{n {+} 1} & \mathcell{n {+} 2} & \mathcell{n {+} 3} \\
\hline
 & & & &
  \colourcells{NavyBlue} & \redcell & \redcell \\
 \hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{} & \mathcell{n{-}1} & \mathcell{n} & \mathcell{n {+} 1} & \mathcell{n {+} 2} & \mathcell{n {+} 3}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm absolutely new to LaTex, so I couldn't figure out the code for this image. What changes would I need to make if I needed to make a closed tile, instead of one side open ones?

Comment: @tex_mate:  Replace  the preamble of the tabular environment: `{*{8}{p{0.7cm}|}}` with `{|*{8}{p{0.7cm}|}}` (i.e· add add a `|` in front of the `*{8}{some code}`. As you may have guessed, `*{8}{...}` indicates the repetition of some pattern in this context.